How to load multiband tiff?
I have a tiff image with 4 bands. Image is about 1GB in size.
When I try to load it it says it cannot allocate buffer for image of dimensions 0x0.
Dimensions are definitely not 0x0.
When I try to load PNG of same size, all works as expected.
Is there something specific that needs to be done for multiband tiffs to load them?

Your best place for questions like this is the QA section in the repository discussions.
Make sure you provide the image in question.
https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp/discussions/categories/q-a
